# reflection followed by a rotation

Tags: linear-algebra

given that $\rho:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be the composition of $\rho=R\circ \sigma_A$, where $R$ is the reflection in the x axis and $\sigma_A$ is the rotation around the point (0,b) through $\pi$

could anyone help me to derive formula for $\rho$?

Comment: Would this composition be a rotation or a reflection, to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you rotate a point $P$  by angle $\pi$ around the centre $C=(0,b)$, the image $P'$  will be in the line joining $P$ and $C$, with $C$ as the mid-point of the line segment $PP'$. Using this fact for any $P=(x,y)$  you can write the formula for $P'=\sigma_A(P)$. And the function $R$ is easy, it simply changes the sign of $y$ co-ordinate keeping $x$ co-ordinate unchanged.

Now compose these two functions in the desired order.